# cli-5.2.0 build phoneGap error no index found

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

When I am trying to build my app using 'cli-5.2.0'  'build phoneGap, I am getting an Error: upload failed; please try again [50] and no index.html present..I updated my config file as described in the phonegap blog:

```
<content src="index.html"/>
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="~1" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

*no index.html present* means you are using the wrong directory structure.

[boilerplate of typical layout](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate)

The following two files should be in the same directory.

```
    +
    index.html
    confix.xml
```

Comment: Both files are in the same directory

Comment: i solved the problem by deleting the application and recreated, the build is successfully but now i face another problem , when i install the apk file its seems like the css file not included in the app

Comment: Make sure you keep all assets (CSS, Javascript, fonts, etc) local to the device. Only use remote loading as a last resort. If you must load CSS remotely, make sure you have an entry in your CSP.

Comment: @jesseMonory650 the css file is local but what i recognize that when i changed the apk file to zip file and i opened it i find that css file not in the same root as the other folder..do you have any idea why this happened?

Comment: if you want to check it i added another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109160/phonegap-build-is-not-updating-all-of-my-files

Comment: If you are on [nitobi](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi), I will have a follow up there.

Comment: Thanks JesseMonroy650, I fixed the issue by delete the css folder then rebuild the app and it is working now