# PhoneGap build is not updating all of my files

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

PhoneGap build is not updating all of my files? I have been using Build for a while, but  now the downloaded application seems like not contains the css file.
I tried to delete the application then upload new zip file and rebuild it but same issue appear. 
I renamed the file extension .apk to .zip and i opened the file I recognize that the css folder is not in the same root as other folder like .js and i think it is the problem, but i don't why this happened.

Any help??

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by deleting the css folder then rebuild the app and it is working now